# suggested they do / suggested they would do?

Tags: grammar

"Yesterday Jodie told Mike she was at school then and suggested they ... in half an hour."

According to Longman dictionary,

> In formal English, you suggest that someone do something, using the
> base form of the verb (=the infinitive without ‘to’).
>
> You can also use the base form of the verb when talking about the
> past.

So, I know that I can use "meet" to complete the sentence above. But I wonder if I can use "would meet" as well. Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There'd be nothing ungrammatical about the version with *would meet*, however it would change the sense of *suggest* from definition 1 below to 2 or 3.

> [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=suggest)
>
> 1. To offer for consideration or action; propose: *suggest things for children to do; suggested that we take a walk*.
> 2. To express or say indirectly: *The police officer seemed to be suggesting that the death was not an accident*.
> 3. To make evident indirectly; intimate or imply: *a silence that suggested disapproval*.

Compare:

Definition 3

> She tilted her regal head in a gesture that **suggested she would
> reserve** judgment on whether or not this particular structure deserved
> the title. (Hearth stone, Lois Greiman)

Definition 1

> While we were talking about his Opening Bat he told me about one of
> his serious collectors who’d sent him an email just after he’d
> received his copy saying “Is that it?”. Brian **suggested he reserve**
> judgement until he’d at least tried playing with it first, and several
> days later there was another email along saying “Ah, now I
> understand...” (blog - [Puzzling Times](http://allardspuzzlingtimes.blogspot.com/2012/08/ipp-thursday-afternoon.html))

The original sentence is a mandative construction (CaGEL p995). These can be either subjunctive mandatives (as in the example given), *should* mandatives, or covert mandatives.

> They suggested he get there early.  [subjunctive mandative]
>
> They suggested he should get there early.  [*should* mandative]
>
> They suggested he gets there there early. [covert mandative]

On the acceptability of these, same source:

> Clear cases of the covert construction are fairly rare, and indeed in
> AmE are of somewhat marginal acceptability. In AmE the subjunctive is
> strongly favoured over the should construction, while BrE shows the
> opposite preference.

*Suggest* has both a mandative and non-mandative interpretation - the addition of *would* into the sentence given changes it from a mandative to a non-mandative one.